# equivalence criteria to find out types of singularities in analytic functions (page 110 conway)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f $ have an isolated singularity at $ z=a $. Suppose that $ f $ is not identically equal to $0$. Suppose that either $$\lim_{z\to a }|z-a|^{s}|f (z)|=0$$ or $$\lim_{z\to a }|z-a|^{s}|f (z)|=\infty$$ holds for some $ s $ in $\mathbb {R} $. I need to show that there is an integer $ m $ such that $$\lim_{z\to a }|z-a|^{s}|f (z)|=0$$ holds if $s \gt m$ and $$ \lim_{z\to a }|z-a|^{s}|f (z)|=\infty $$ holds if $ s \lt m $.

I assumed that the first holds and could find out such a m (namely the [m]). Now I am assuming that the second holds. Then  suppose that $$ g (z)= (z-a)^{s_o}f (z)$$ where $ s_o \in \mathbb {R} $ is the number for which $$\lim_{z\to a }|z-a|^{s}|f (z)|=\infty$$ holds. Then $ g (z) $ has an isolated singularity at $ a $. Moreover $$\lim_{z \to a} |g (z)|=\infty $$. Hence $ g (z) $ has a pole at $ a $. (Say of order $ m $) Then $ g (z) $ has a laurent series expansion about $ z=a$. Thus $$ g(z)= c_{-m}(z-a)^{-m}+...c_{0}+... $$. This gives that  $$ f (z)(z-a)^{s_{o}+m}= c_{-m}(z-a)^{-m}+. . . $$. If $s_{o}+m$ is an integer then we are done. But if it is not then I am unable to conclude.

Second way:

Suppose that there is an $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{z \to a}|z-a|^{s}|f(z)|=\infty$$. I took cases. Suppose $s \ge 0$. If $s=0$ then we are done. Otherwise I claim that $$\lim_{z \to a}|f(z)|=\infty$$. If not then it exists ( i.e is a finite number). Then $$\lim_{z \to a} |f(z)||z-a|=0$$. But this cannot happen. Hence the claim is settled. But then $f(z)$ has a pole at $a$. And the order of the pole will be my required integer.

Again I cannot proceed when $s \lt 0$.

Thanks for the help!!